# Cloudfront Multiple Origins and Distributions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having my site run on AWS and we are using Cloudfront for two origins:

1) Main Site: EC2+ Loadbalancer
2) Blog: S3

Then we created a behavior with /blog*, which we thought was that everything including Blog + Any article in Blog/ would go to the S3 website as well. Now our expectation was that they would link to the S3, so if someone hit www.mysite.com/blog it would go to S3, but it does not seem to work. For the /blog, nothing happens.

Then for anything e.g. /blog/article1.html we just get a "not exists" from S3, which means that we are not hitting the right endpoint. So my questions:

1) Is there a way to link /blog to S3 in this way?

2) Do we need to have mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blog as the URL? or can we have mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com?

3) Then would the articles need to be in: mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blog or mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com?

Seems Like we are doing something wrong. The fact that any change requires like 30 minutes of waiting does not help either...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is possible to do what you are planning. Let me answer your questions inline.

> 1) Is there a way to link /blog to S3 in this way?

Yes. You can add the blog S3 Origin and behavior with route /blog/* to S3.

> 2) Do we need to have
>   mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blog as the URL? or can
>   we have mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com?

If you are hoping to map the same domain with subpath (aka /blog/article1.html) then you need to put the articles inside /blog/ path inside S3 bucket. Make sure in the Origin config not to add any paths.

> 3) Then would the articles need to be in: 
>   mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blog or
>   mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com?

Articles needs to be inside /blog/ in S3. If you need to use a different routing mechanism you can still do it with Lambda Edge. But that require some coding.

Comment: Awesome! This saved years of my life!